# php simplexml_load_string not working on XML string

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to read XML string using PHP function **simplexml_load_string** but I get below errors

```
Message: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found

Message: simplexml_load_string(): &lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;

Message: simplexml_load_string(): ^
```

I get XML sting in variable as below (var_dum). I get this XML string from another file using fgetc I also tried '/xml' at end but it gives same error

```
     string(3155) "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <LEIRecord xmlns:lei="http://www.gleif.org/data/schema/leidata/2016">
          <LEI>029200013A5N6ZD0F605</LEI>
          <Entity>
            <LegalName xml:lang="en">AFRINVEST SECURITIES LIMITED</LegalName>
            <OtherEntityNames>
              <OtherEntityName xml:lang="fr" type="ALTERNATIVE_LANGUAGE_LEGAL_NAME">AFRINVEST SECURITIES LIMITED</OtherEntityName>
            </OtherEntityNames>
            <LegalAddress xml:lang="en">
              <FirstAddressLine>27 GERRARD ROAD</FirstAddressLine>
              <AdditionalAddressLine>IKOYI</AdditionalAddressLine>
              <City>LAGOS</City>
              <Region>NG-LA</Region>
              <Country>NG</Country>
              <PostalCode>23401</PostalCode>
            </LegalAddress>
            <LegalJurisdiction>NG</LegalJurisdiction>
            <LegalForm>
              <EntityLegalFormCode>8888</EntityLegalFormCode>
              <OtherLegalForm>LIMITED</OtherLegalForm>
            </LegalForm>
            <EntityStatus>ACTIVE</EntityStatus>
          </Entity>
        </LEIRecord>
    "
```

Code :

```
json_decode(json_encode((array)simplexml_load_string($data)), TRUE);
```

Comment: Show your `simplexml_load_string ` function calling code

Comment: updated in question

Comment: The `$data` is escaped from `HTML chars`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the `$data` is escaped from `HTML chars`...

Try to decode before pass it to `simplexml_load_string`..

**Instead of**

```
json_decode(json_encode((array)simplexml_load_string($data)), TRUE);
```

**Try this...**

```
json_decode(json_encode((array)simplexml_load_string(htmlspecialchars_decode($data))), TRUE);
```